# I want to compile the Istio source code in a Centos7 environment, but there are a lot of problems

Tags: linux, go, istio

```
[root@VM-0-15-centos istio]# make build
useradd: UID 0 is not unique
ISTIO_OUT=/work/out/linux_amd64 ISTIO_BIN=/gobin GOOS_LOCAL=linux bin/retry.sh SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL bin/init.sh
Skipping envoy debug. Set DEBUG_IMAGE to download.
/work /work
Downloading envoy: https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-build/proxy/envoy-alpha-432cb173c1e497ae3b05c2af3dadddc91ffa8c65.tar.gz to

real    0m5.408s
user    0m0.731s
sys     0m0.296s
cp: cannot create regular file '': No such file or directory
Unexpected failure: Skipping envoy debug. Set DEBUG_IMAGE to download.
/work /work
Downloading envoy: https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-build/proxy/envoy-alpha-432cb173c1e497ae3b05c2af3dadddc91ffa8c65.tar.gz to

real    0m5.408s
user    0m0.731s
sys     0m0.296s
cp: cannot create regular file '': No such file or directory
Makefile.core.mk:227: recipe for target '/work/out/linux_amd64/istio_is_init' failed
make[1]: *** [/work/out/linux_amd64/istio_is_init] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Comment: According to https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html, the `--retry-connrefused` flag was added to `curl` in version 7.52.0. According to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/, the packaged version of `curl` is 7.29.0. If you're using the packaged version, you'll need to install and use a more recent version.

Comment: thanks But I ran into this problem again

Comment: Skipping envoy debug. Set DEBUG_IMAGE to download.
~/go/src/istio.io/istio ~/go/src/istio.io/istio
Downloading envoy: https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-build/proxy/envoy-alpha-0f258ab063247e4237e7734dde90ff5731e1825c.tar.gz to

real    0m3.562s
user    0m0.706s
sys     0m0.321s

Comment: cp: cannot create regular file ‘’: No such file or directory
make: *** [/root/go/src/istio.io/istio/out/linux_amd64/istio_is_init] Error 1

Comment: now, run into this problem:fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.

Comment: Unable to find image 'gcr.io/istio-testing/build-tools:master-2021-03-01T22-30-49' locally

Comment: Unable to find image 'gcr.io/istio-testing/build-tools:master-2021-03-01T22-30-49' locally
^Cmake: *** [docker] Interrupt